# How i can submit multiple objects inside the form post values to be added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a create view to add answers to a question, currently the user can only add one answer at the same time when he clicks on the submit button, instead of this i want the user to be able to insert multiple answers objects into the same view and then the system to add all these new answer objects to the database after the user click on the submit button, my current view looks as the follow:-

```
@model Elearning.Models.Answer 
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Create"; 
} 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id = "remove">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Answer", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "remove"
}))

 {
     <div id = "returnedquestion">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Answer</legend> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 

    </fieldset> 
     <input type= "hidden" name = "questionid" value = @ViewBag.questionid>
     <input type= "hidden" name = "assessmentid" value = @ViewBag.assessmentid>
     <input type="submit" value="Add answer" />
 </div>
 }
 </div>
```

and the action methods look as the follow:-

```
public ActionResult Create(int questionid)//, int assessmentid)
{
    ViewBag.questionid = questionid;
    Answer answer = new Answer();
              return PartialView("_answer",answer);
} 

//
// POST: /Answer/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int questionid, Answer a)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        repository.AddAnswer(a);
        repository.Save();
        return PartialView("_details",a);
    }
    return View(a);}
```

**so how i can modify the above code to be able to insert multiple answer objects at the same view and then submit these answers objects at the same time when the user click on the submit button?**

Comment: Hello. I've read your answer since I'm surfing for an answer to a current problem. Similar to the original question, I'm looking to submit multiple objects stored in a table but it seems I can only submit one form. In that way I'm looking for a way to submit one form with information of multiple objects and save it into a database. I have presented my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067465/core-submit-multiple-forms-and-save-each-one-of-them but wanted to thank you since I believe I might found an answer here. If you have any comment on my question feel free to give me one.

Answer (score 1):

Try Post a List
Add input by javascript when user click "Add Answer".
And when submit the form ,it will post all answer data to binding to List

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anwserCount = 1;
    $("#addbutton").click(function () {
        $("#AnwsersDiv")
       .append("<input type='text' name='Anwsers[" + anwserCount + "]'/>");
        anwserCount += 1;
    });
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div id="AnwsersDiv">
    <input type="text" name="Anwsers[0]" />
</div>
<input id="addbutton" type="button" value="Add answer" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Model

```
public class Answer
{
    public List<String> Anwsers { get; set; }
}
```

When submit the form

[image]

Comment: thanks for your kind reply - i think you mean to create AnswerViewModel and not QuestionViewModel- never mind; but in this way i am restricting the user to insert only 3 answers ,, what if he wants to insert for example 4 answers or only 2 answers.  Second thing i do not think that it will work if i am setting the id of the object as in viewModel.Questions.Add(new Question() { Id = 1 });

Comment: the count of answer depends on how many questions when get this questionaire. Setting the id just for mapping questions in database

Comment: mmm.. i think i misunderstand your question. Your Answer is a List<String> Object ?

Comment: I also struck in same scenario and was searching for solution like this. Thanks a lot I got this answer of yours. Thanks Friend:)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

*Conclusion*: you should make the post action with `ICollection<Answer>` Parameter, then it will be easy to get them when you post your main form, and create the appropriate QUESTION object, then save them all with only one submit.