# Core: Submit multiple forms and save each one of them

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-core

I wonder if it is possible.

I have a view which has multiple tab-panes. Each tab-pane correspond to a `Store`.

Inside each `Store` there is a table which contains information of all the `Machines` assigned to that `Store`. The information of each `Machine` is presented in a row. Each row is wrapped as a individual form.

This is basically a sales report, so in each row the user can introduce how many sells were made for each `Machine`.

**The objetive:** I'm trying to submit all the records at a `Store` level. I mean, for each `Store` submit all the results introduced for each one of the `Machines` in that store.

Here is the view:

[image]

What alternatives do I have? I've read somewhere is it only possible to submit one form at a time? If this is the case, how would it be possible to differentiate each row and submit them separately?